# Facing issue to install homebrew on macbook

Tags: homebrew

curl: (28) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 after 75269 ms: Operation timed out

I'm tried to install homebrew on my macbook using `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` this commant but it can't works, how to install homebrew ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue today with my newly bought macbook pro. Here is how i resolved the issue

1. I am using jiofiber as my ISP and had not changed the default DNS settings. This was the root cause for the issue.
2. Go to the DNS settings and update the DNS server to point to googles public DNS servers (8.8.8.8) and save the settings

This resolved the issue for me. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use your mobile network for downloading homebrew

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).